# Multiple and different images not responsive css

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I have a section in a website with logos (images) of a lot of brands
So In the desktop version I have 8 columns and 3 rows... And it looks fine, 
but in the mobile version it looks awful.

This is a pic of the website

[image: Website]

And this is a pic of the mobile version

[image: Mobile]

This is the css code

```
aside.clients {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
aside.clients img {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an idea about how you want they should actually looks like on mobile? Are they not centered, rater than not span all over the device with... (?)

Comment: use media queries to resize the images. Here is some documenation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: We'll need to see the html as well. It's an easy fix though. Essentially you need to edit the width of your columns when they are within your mobile defined range using media queries. So instead of having 1 column at 100% width, you might want two or three columns.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make some adjustments here to suit your needs. I've made some presumptions as to what your html looks like:

```
// html
<aside class="clients">
    <div>
        <img src="..." alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- .... repeat x23 ... -->
</aside>

// css
aside.clients div {width:50%;float:left;} /* show 2 images per row for mobile */
aside.clients div img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
@media (min-width:768px){ /* show 4  images per row for tablet */
    aside.clients div {width:25%} 
}
@media (min-width:992px){ /* show 8  images per row for desktop */
    aside.clients div {width:12.5%} 
}
```

note: it also requires your images to all be the same dimensions otherwise the new rows will not wrap onto the next line correctly. Otherwise of that's not the case, use css to clear the required div. eg: nth-child(2n+1) {clear:left;}

https://jsfiddle.net/ojk02cya/